# I have to configure job which run on every weekdays (MON- FRI) 2 PM starting date 5-Jan-2019, considering today's date is 26-dec-2018

Tags: cron

I have to configure job which run on every weekdays (MON- FRI) 2 PM  starting date 5-Jan-2019, considering today's date is 26-dec-2018

`0 14 * * 1-5`  (this will work for mon-fri 2 Pm) but i need to add start date as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add start date because this is not how `cron` work. Moreover the relation between date and month is **AND**, but between date, month and day of week is **OR**. So the best way is to add this login in script. Can be something like:

```
TDATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
if [ "$TDATE" -ge 20190105 ]
  then exec your code
fi
```

Comment: This will help.

Comment: @VarunShah, if you feel this is helpful you can upvote the answer or/and mark it as accepted